# Make a dynamic function on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have button like this

```
<button ng-click="method = 'create'; title = 'Create'>create</button>
<button ng-click="method = 'update'; title = 'Update'>update</button>
```

and this

```
<button ng-click="create(param)">{{ title }}</button>
<button ng-click="update(param)">{{ title }}</button>
```

Code above works fine, but I want to make it dynamic.

so I change it like following.

```
<button ng-click="{{ method }}(param)">{{ title }}</button>
```

This does not work, I dont know why, although if I do inspect element, code above generates corrects code as mentioned before.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use of [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
<button ng-click="this[method](param)">{{ title }}</button>
```

`this` points to current scope object so with `this[method]` you can access method via variable name.

Answer (score 2):

This didn't work for me.. and..

I didn't want to deal with having html code in my angular app, or directives, or the use of eval. so I just wrapped my existing functions in a function:

```
$scope.get_results = function(){

    return {
            message: "A message", 
            choice1: {message:"choice 1 message", f: function(){$scope.alreadyDefinedFunction1()}},
            choice2: {message:"choice 2 message", f: function(){$scope.alreadyDefinedFunction2()}},
        };
}
```

in a different function:

```
$scope.results2 = $scope.get_results();
```

Snippet of use in html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu scroll-div">
  <li><a ng-click="results2.choice1.f()">{{results_2_menu.choice1.message}}</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="results2.choice2.f()">{{results_2_menu.choice2.message}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Was based on this js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cdaringe/FNky4/1/

Comment: This worked for me! The accepted answer however did not. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This syntax seems working well

```
<button ng-click="this[method(param)]">{{ title }}</button>
```

starting from the suggestion of user [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq) and as the suggestion wasn't working with angularjs 1.6.4, I put the closing braket after the param value.