# How to run code after an Angular modal window ($uibModalInstance) opens?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

I need to respond at some events in a modal window.

Take this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/bLNRLj?editors=1010) as base. 
Suppose an (demo) need to alert the label content on click on **all the labels** in the modal window:

[image]

my code in the modal's controller has no effect

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
  .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',
              function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $('label').click(function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: Why are you using jquery code in an Angular controller? Just add an ng-click to the label.

Comment: Suppose I have no access to the HTML code, only to JS, the generated labels number (I need to attach the click to *all* labels) is not know in advance.

Comment: Here, I made a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cgxaEKsBtcoID3FQFWqs?p=preview), for you to try and adjust how you need it.

Comment: @Serge for a dynamic approach you would need to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) your html instead (for `ng-click` to work), where unknown functions should be added with a [bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252041/make-a-dynamic-function-on-ng-click)

Comment: In fact I have some "social" links, like facebook, twitter etc sharing, that should open in a new little window popup on click :)

Comment: @Serge ah yes, good old nested modals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't have any effect because when it executes, the template is not a part of the DOM yet. If you put this line of code in the controller:

```
console.log($('label').length);
```

you can see that it returns 0. So, all you need is to wait until the moment the template loads. There is one common trick in Angular, which helps in such situations: put your code in a $timeout service, like this:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $('label').on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e);
  });
});
```

Timeout will put the code at the very end of your current execution pipeline, and at that moment the popup template will be in DOM.

But this is a dirty hack of course :) More Angular way, in case you need to write some jQuery code, is to write a separate directive and apply it to the respective elements in your template. And don't forget about the huge variety of native directives, such as "ng-click" and etc.

Comment: A bit modified [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/paulmordont/pen/ddPzag?editors=1011)

Answer (score 1):

```
$uibModalInstance.rendered.then(function(){
  // run your code here and you are fine.
});
```